# Online store deployment error, with many models

Tags: python, django, heroku

As soon as I click on the link, a standard error is written to me. Tried to increase the request processing time but the error persists. I also updated the database completely and changed the host address. Before adding a new model, everything worked, but as soon as I made a couple of changes it stopped working.

Here is my code https://github.com/Daryna00/My

File location

```
Preset
  >home
  >media
  >merchan
  >order
  >Preset
  >product
  >staticfiles
  >templates
  >'
  >db.sqlite3
  >debug.log
  >manage.py
  >Procfile
  >requirements.txt
  >runtime.txt
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn Preset.wsgi
```

After entering the command such errors.

```
    (venv) D:\PycharmProjects\My\Preset>heroku logs --tail
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661822+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661822+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661823+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661823+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/home/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661835+00:00 app[web.1]: from .views import index, what_is_it, sign_in, register, logout_user, my_page, ajax_reg_login, contact, change_order_count, delete_from_card, add_to_card, get_pdf, questions_answer
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661835+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/home/views.py", line 19, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661836+00:00 app[web.1]: from xhtml2pdf import pisa
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661836+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/pisa.py", line 18, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661836+00:00 app[web.1]: from xhtml2pdf.default import DEFAULT_CSS
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661837+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/default.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661837+00:00 app[web.1]: from xhtml2pdf import util
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661837+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/util.py", line 28, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661838+00:00 app[web.1]: import httplib
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661838+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib.py", line 345
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661838+00:00 app[web.1]: print "reply:", repr(line)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661840+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661840+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2021-02-01T11:48:20.661973+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-01 11:48:20 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751720+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-01 11:48:20 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751723+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751724+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751725+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751725+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751726+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751726+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751727+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751734+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751735+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751735+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751735+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751736+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751736+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751737+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751737+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751737+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751738+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751739+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751739+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751739+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751740+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751740+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751740+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751741+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/Preset/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751741+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751741+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751741+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751742+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751742+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751743+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751743+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config.ready()
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751743+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751744+00:00 app[web.1]: self.module.autodiscover()
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751744+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751745+00:00 app[web.1]: autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751745+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751745+00:00 app[web.1]: import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751746+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751746+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751746+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751747+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751747+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751747+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751748+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751748+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751749+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/home/admin.py", line 10, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751749+00:00 app[web.1]: path('', include('home.urls'))
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751749+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751750+00:00 app[web.1]: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751750+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751750+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751750+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751751+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751751+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751751+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751752+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751752+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751752+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/home/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751765+00:00 app[web.1]: from .views import index, what_is_it, sign_in, register, logout_user, my_page, ajax_reg_login, contact, change_order_count, delete_from_card, add_to_card, get_pdf, questions_answer
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751765+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/home/views.py", line 19, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751766+00:00 app[web.1]: from xhtml2pdf import pisa
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751766+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/pisa.py", line 18, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751766+00:00 app[web.1]: from xhtml2pdf.default import DEFAULT_CSS
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751767+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/default.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751767+00:00 app[web.1]: from xhtml2pdf import util
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751768+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/util.py", line 28, in <module>
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751768+00:00 app[web.1]: import httplib
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751768+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib.py", line 345
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751768+00:00 app[web.1]: print "reply:", repr(line)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751769+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751770+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2021-02-01T11:48:20.751908+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-01 11:48:20 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-02-01T11:48:20.859508+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-01 11:48:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-02-01T11:48:20.859608+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-01 11:48:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-02-01T11:48:20.931168+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-02-01T11:48:20.980687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-02-01T11:48:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-01T11:49:26.683179+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-presets-shop.herokuapp.com request_id=99f63ae3-f189-4b14-9864-128f82962b14 fwd="93.74.99.144" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-01T11:49:27.610373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=my-presets-shop.herokuapp.com request_id=31e1158a-7239-4432-ba8c-d3b944598038 fwd="93.74.99.144" dyno= connect=
 service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: `print "reply:", repr(line)` This is not a valid syntax in python3. It should be a function.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was worth disconnecting the library httpsproxy-urllib2 and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Heroku's dynos don't have a filesystem that persists across deploys, a file-based database like SQLite3 isn't going to be suitable. It's a great DB for development/quick prototypes, though.

Heroku do have a Postgres offering however that will suit - with a free tier and a basic $9/month tier that are good for hobby/small projects. The biggest benefit over SQLite is that you get backups that you wouldn't get otherwise (plus all the other Postgres features).

There's a guide to updating your settings.py to use Postgres here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings

Answer (score 0):

When the library httpsproxy-urllib2 and its components were removed, everything worked.